How to create a Fail2Ban filter?
I'm trying to create a Fail2Ban filter that catches all response codes except 200 or 412 across all destination paths. Here is a sample of my log format:
INFO [2024-06-13 10:23:58] 172.20.101.132 "PostmanRuntime/7.37.3" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/login 200 0.084 NA
INFO [2024-06-13 10:56:04] 172.20.101.132 "PostmanRuntime/7.37.3" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/estado_actual 200 0.369 RQQSLA
INFO [2024-06-13 11:00:32] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/estado_actual 200 0.339 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:00:34] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/info_paciente 200 0.172 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:02:56] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/registro_tiempo 412 0.045 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:12] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/estado_actual 200 0.048 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:13] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/info_paciente 200 0.033 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:13] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/registro_tiempo 200 0.063 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:50] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/estado_actual 200 0.04 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:50] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/info_paciente 200 0.043 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:03:51] 172.31.25.145 "python-requests/2.21.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 POST /micirugia/registro_tiempo 200 0.084 NOFDPY
INFO [2024-06-13 11:20:06] 172.20.100.105 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 GET / 405 0.012 NA
INFO [2024-06-13 11:21:06] 172.20.100.105 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 GET / 405 0.012 NA
INFO [2024-06-13 11:22:06] 172.20.100.105 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 GET / 405 0.012 NA
INFO [2024-06-13 11:23:06] 172.20.100.105 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0" 172.30.19.97:18000 GET / 405 0.012 NA

The log format includes:

The word "INFO"
The date/time in brackets
The source IP address
The user agent
The destination IP address
The request method and destination path
The response code
The processing time in milliseconds
A serial number string, which may be "NA"

I have tried using this regex filter without success:
failregex = ^INFO \[\] <HOST> ".*?" \S+:\d+ (GET|POST) .* \S+ (400|404|505) \d+\.\d{3} NA$

How can I create a Fail2Ban filter that correctly matches all response codes except 200 or 412?

\[\] matches literally those two characters adjacent to each other; but your sample contains no occurrences of []

It's really not clear what exactly you are hoping to match, or why you thought this regex would match anything resembling what you say you want.

i made a typo when posting my current filter

What happens if you change to \[[^]]+\]? (Or the less precise \[.*?\] you already used elsewhere.)
